# C strcmp to compare string with first x characters of array

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I want to compare two strings but the word i am looking for is in a array of 40 characters. so what i want is to compare words, with the first 40 characters of the array.

How do i do this?

So :

```
words[1] = "apple"
words2[1] = a
words2[2] = p
words2[3] = p
words2[4] = l 
words2[5] = e
```

Code

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("%s\n", words[j]);

    if (strcmp (words[j], words2[]) == 0)
    {
    // found it
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 `array` does need to be null-terminated, just to point that out

Answer (score 1):

strstr will take two null terminated strings and tell you if one is in the other. This example looks for `word` in `array`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char array[] = {"an array of several words"};
    char word[] = { " of "};
    char *pchar = NULL;

    pchar = strstr ( array, word);
    if ( pchar) {
        printf ( "found %s in %s\n", word, array);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fine but how is it related to the question ? In the example, the array does not seem to be null terminated, and I understand the question as *is string equals to beginning of the array*, and you answer to *is a string contained in another string* :-( . Moreover, you use pointless and rather confusing brackets around your strings. Can't understand how you got +1 ...